# Is there a way to dynamically resize remote images in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, media

Part of the site, I'm making has a YouTube video gallery. I want to display the thumbnails in list format but I need to resize them first. Using theme('`image_style`', etc) would be the simplest solution but it seems to only work on local files. Is there a way to get this to work with remote files?

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Imagecache External](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external) module

> Imagecache External is a utility module to allow you to use
>   imagecache(D6)/image derivatives (D7) with external images.

Comment: I've tried adding it but it doesn't seem to work. I've set permissions to allow anyone and switched it to black list with an empty list. Nothing is still getting through. The img tag isn't even showing up.